# Security of password-protected folder for admin directory

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, security

As far as I know, the security of webserver (apache or nginx) password-protected folder is higher than that of $_SESSION defined access level. However, the common method (at least in CMS models) is to use the latter one instead of protecting the entire admin folder by webserver.

What are the pros and cons of using password-protected folder for administration of a CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro Http Access

- It is saver
- It is easier

Pro Session

- "Password Recovery" Form
- Custom Page Layout (You see where you are.)

Answer (score -2):

As a matter of fact, you **cannot** protect a folder with PHP sessions. Just because it's PHP sessions and works obviously for the PHP files only.

If you are talking of protecting PHP scripts, you have answered it yourself: sessions are more flexible and thus more widely chosen.

As for the security, I doubt that web-server-based Basic HTTP auth is more secure than session-based. Digest one is indeed more secure though

Comment: My knowledge about security issues or hacking methods is very limited; but I thought that a session can be faked by dealing with the files in public area which are accessible (e.g. sql injection to change access level). For attacking Basic HTTP auth, one needs to attack the whole server to access the password outside the public folder (and of course the password is encrypted and so forth...)

Comment: dunno what are you talking about faking files in public area, but if your site is vulnerable to SQL injection, the database would be compromised from the public pages as well.

Comment: I am crystal clear: 1. if someone access your database (at least to alter his membership type) can access to all admin features; but in password-protected system, no one can access to the admin features unless accessing to the entire system. 2. In common CMSes (e.g. wordpress) it is recommended to add higher security by password protecting the admin direction. There are plugins for this purpose. 3. Upon saving session on cookies (client-side), an attacker can fake the stored session (not an easy task of course).